# is EmitDefaultValue set to false will work for int, long, float and DateTime in WCF and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

EmitDefaultValue set to false not working for int and other data types, please advice me. I want to remove the null value fields from my xml. It seems working only for string types.

Is these any other better approach to achieve this?

Please do the needful.

DataContract

```
 [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class AddressContract
    {

        private int addressTypeIdField = 0;

        private int parentAddressTypeIDField = 0;

        private string postCodeField = null;

        private string phoneFlagField = null;

        private string emailFlagField = null;

        private float geoCodeLattitudeField = 0.0F;

        private float geoCodeLongitudeField = 0.0F;

        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public int AddressTypeId
        {
            get
            {
                return this.addressTypeIdField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.addressTypeIdField = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public int ParentAddressTypeID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.parentAddressTypeIDField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.parentAddressTypeIDField = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string PostCode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.postCodeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.postCodeField = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string PhoneFlag
        {
            get
            {
                return this.phoneFlagField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.phoneFlagField = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string EmailFlag
        {
            get
            {
                return this.emailFlagField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.emailFlagField = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public float GeoCodeLattitude
        {
            get
            {
                return this.geoCodeLattitudeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.geoCodeLattitudeField = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public float GeoCodeLongitude
        {
            get
            {
                return this.geoCodeLongitudeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.geoCodeLongitudeField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your DataContract?

Comment: EmitDefaultValue should be the correct approach for all those types.

Comment: @Buh Buh - EmitDefaultValue not working except string type

Comment: Your contract looks correct.  How are you generating/viewing your xml?

Comment: After having misunderstood it all :) I had to test and the contract works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue.aspx

It is sure that it can work with int value as well